# How would I combine these two pieces of code in Python?

Tags: python, email, network-monitoring

I want to find a way to combine these two pieces of code into a single function that will send me an email whenever a certain server goes down (i.e server no longer receives pings). How would I go about to do that with these 2 code segments?

```
import smtplib
import subprocess
##Ping
    hostname = "x.x.x.x"
    output = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe",hostname],stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    print(output)

    if ('unreachable' in output):
        print("Offline")

##Email
    fromaddr = 'someone@gmail.com'
    toaddrs  = 'somebody@somewhere.com'
    msg = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % ('SERVER STATUS', 'Server is Down')
    # Login info
    username = 'user'
    password = 'pass'

    # Outgoing SMTP
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg,)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Create a function `send_email` & then just call the function if your `if` block?! Also, if the mail is being sent to different people according to the server going down, you'll need to have a lookup table for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just include it in your `if` block:

```
import smtplib
import subprocess
##Ping
    hostname = "x.x.x.x"
    output = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe",hostname],stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    print(output)

    if ('unreachable' in output):
        print("Offline")
        fromaddr = 'someone@gmail.com'
        toaddrs  = 'somebody@somewhere.com'
        msg = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % ('SERVER STATUS', 'Server is Down')
        # Login info
        username = 'user'
        password = 'pass'

        # Outgoing SMTP
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username,password)
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg,)
        server.quit()
```